# Node Express Res SendFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having trouble with the res.send context. I do have the `index.html` in my directory and it doesn't work as I'm expecting to. It just doesn't show my HTML file.

```
app.listen(8081, function(){
    console.log("Servidor rodando na url http://localhost:8081");
});

app.get("/sendfile", function(req,res){
    res.send("Página SENDFILE")
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "index.html");
});
```

Here's what is showing in the localhost page:

[image: What is showing:]

Here's my directory:

[image: My_dir]

Comment: Your issue is that `res.send()` sends the response immediately and you can only send one response to a request, so `sendFile()` is ignored.

Comment: You can't do multiple sends inside a single response..  You either sends some text, or you send a file, not both.

Comment: Also -> `__dirname + "index.html"`  use `path.join(__dirname, "index.html")`..  Or you will be trying to send files like -> `c:\appdirindex.html`.  aka  no path separator.

Comment: I tried to, but:
```app.get("/sendfile", function(req,res){res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));});```

This is what is showing when the web opens:

ReferenceError: path is not defined at c:\Users\Edgelson\Desktop\Web\Node\Freespace\node_470af21675bfd.tmp:27:18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it should produce error of 
**`Headers can't be set once they are sent`.**

Becuse once the response from :
**`res.send('Pagina SendFile')`** is sent it won't send **`index.html`** file.

You should first set the view Engine like this :

**`app.set('view engine', 'html');`** in your **`server.js`** file
And important of all you should keep all `HTML` files in views then set view engine & finally send using :

**`res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + 'index.html')`**

Comment: Hey, thank you! It works. I'm going to put the code here if someone needs:

```app.get("/sendfile", function(req,res){
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});```

Answer (score 0):

`app.get('/sendfile', async (req, res) => { ... })` block defines a route handler for the HTTP GET request to the `/sendfile` endpoint. When a client sends a GET request to this endpoint, the code inside the block will execute.

Inside the route handler, `res.sendFile()` is used to send the file located at the specified path to the client.

- A single HTTP GET request can only have one response. In Express, the `res.send()` or `res.sendFile()` method is used to send a response back to the client. Once the response is sent, the request-response cycle is complete.
- You cannot use both at a time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).